# Интересное свойство require_once

Tags: php, require_once

Здравсвуйте. Есть фаил send.php. Он принимает (метод POST , это не важно) адреса-емейлы, и делает рассылку. Массив емейлов отправлял в файле emails.php AJAX - сом. При этом сама отправка (в коде) происходит с паузами 1 минута, после 10 писем, т.е. на одну отправку уходит около 20 минут. Отправлять можно было несколько рассылок сразу. Поясню, ввожу 200 адресов, нажимаю отправит, опять ввожу 200 ардесов нажимаю отправить - все работает без пауз, т.е. параллельно.

Но как только я захотел, чтобы фаил send.php записывал еще в Базу данных время и емейлы, добавив код (подключение к переменным с именами таблиц БД)

```
require_once(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  ."begin_ofis.php");
```

как тут же мои параллельные рассылки перестали работать и стали последовательными, т.е. ввожу 200 ардесов, отправляю, жду, жду, жду, отправляю следующие.

Почему это происходит? И как этот обойти?

Comment: Вот ты какой, северный спамер! Не буду лишний раз говорить, что здесь нет телепатов, имеющих представление о содержании кода в страницах `send.php`, `emails.php` и `begin_ofis.php`, но скорее всего база блокирует одновременное подключение для нескольких сессий для одного пользователя.

Comment: Да. Возможно, а как это обойти? если, к примеру, в каждом файле закрыть соединение mysqli_close ?

Comment: База не будет ничего блокировать. Скорей всего где то автор налажал в коде. Подозреваю что require_once выполняется в цикле, но разумеется без кода ничего определенного сказать нельзя.

Comment: нет , автор ничего не налажал :) Код самый простой,  вкратце самая суть:  
//Отправялем AJAX методом post//
emails.php (jquery AJAX): $.post("send.php", {'email': str_email , 'subject': str_subject , 'message': str_message  }

//Подключаемся к файлу с названиеми таблиц и к базеданных//
begin_ofis.php:$dbc = mysqli_connect($config ->host, $config ->user, $config ->password, $config ->db) or die(mysql_error());
$history_mailing = $config ->dbprefix.'_history_mailing';


//принемаем, отправляем функцией mail PHP  //
send.php: mail(   $myemail, $subjectMy, $final_message, $headers);

Comment: А как вы делает параллельную рассылку, когда адреса берутся из базы?
Небось лимитами?
т.е.

выборка с лимитом
отправка
выборка с лимитом
отправка
так?

Comment: Не совсем, схема такая: в файле "рассылка.пхп" находятся две формы отправки. первая - отправляет AJAX  и получает емейлы, вставляя их во вторую форму с помощью javascript. т.е. емейлы при отправки уже есть, это тоже самое, если бы я их брал, к примеру, с текстового файла и вставлял в форму отправки. При получении эта срока из емейлов разбивается в массив и с помощью цикла отправляется последовательно.
Все работало прекрасно, я перечитал много форумом по поводу много задачности PHP или многопоточности и все писали "нет, для этого PHP  не предназначен".

Comment: но с помощью AJAX это возможно сделать.

Comment: Сейчас схема такая: приходят емейлы -> подключение к БД -> запись в БД -> расслыка.
Но как только я добавляю фаил, который подключается к БД, мне приходится ждать когда первая рассылка закончит свое действие.
Возможно из-за того что фаил рассылки занят, он блокирует подключение к БД, не смотря на то, что от неё не какой работы больше не нужно. На мой взгляд, это странно, потому что, во-первых каким образом сервер понимает что это тот же клиент, который работает с файлом рассылки, ведь запрос отправлен AJAX, а во-вторых, БД закончила свою работу тогда почему она не "отпускает" ?

Comment: Выложите код, а то ничего не понятно.  а AJAX запрос у вас асинхронный? Как вы узнали, что вы что "Но как только я добавляю фаил, который подключается к БД, мне приходится ждать"? Добавляю это подключаю?